# pysvn log can not get Head Revision commit log when file was deleted

Tags: logging, head, revision, pysvn

my step is：
0、check out repos test to work copy at g:/test1 and g:/test2
1、Add a file called f1.txt to repos and commit it at g:/test1/f1.txt
2、Make some change to f1.txt and commit  at g:/test1/f1.tx
3、Update g:/test2 to head rversion then delete g:/test2/f1.txt and commit
4、Use pysvnClient.log to get head reversion log message get Error!But get lower Revision log message will sucess.
I tried almost every log parameters combination but no oen work!
I also try peg_revision,revision_start,revision_end params values but none works!
Many thanks to help me get rigth result or show me your code!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal svn behavior, which pysvn exposes.

The problem is that after the commit in (4) the file does not exist in HEAD.

You have to use a peg revision to help svn find the file and its history.

You should see the same problem with the svn command.

Barry (pysvn maintainer)

Comment: As I said,I also tried peg_revision,revision_start,revision_end etc. available params values and combinations but none works!

Comment: The peg revision must be a revision where the file existed. Try experimenting with svn log command. Once the svn log command works it can be converted into a pysvn script.